# Diretiva: bloquear duplo click em um botão

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Ola,

Eu tenho uma diretiva para bloquear o duplo clique nos botões do meu sistema... 
Porem, ao clicar em um botão que esteja "chamando" a diretiva, ele não faz a função dele (ex: se o botão for submit, não acontece o submit).

Eu gostaria de usa-la para **vários botões** com **funções diferentes**.

Diretiva

```js
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[blockClicks]'
})
export class NoDblClickMatDirective {

    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        const button = (event.srcElement.disabled === undefined) ? event.srcElement.parentElement : event.srcElement;
        button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            button.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Module Diretiva

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NoDblClickMatDirective } from "./nodblclickmat.directive";

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [NoDblClickMatDirective],
    exports: [NoDblClickMatDirective]
})
export class NoDblClickMatDirectiveModule { }
```

Trecho Html

```html
<button class="btn btn-info" blockClicks>Entrar</button>
```

Comment: Presumo que testou isso no Google Chrome. Nunca cheguei a pesquisar a fundo, mas há navegadores que não fazem a submissão do formulário se você definir o botão como `disabled`. Se não me engano aconteceu isso um tempo atrás e no Firefox funcionava normalmente, o Chrome bloqueava.

Comment: Hmmm, @AndersonCarlosWoss, vou testar em outros navegadores... Se caso for isso mesmo, eu resolveria como?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Você está certo, no FireFox funcionou...

Comment: Ouço muito isso :D Geralmente você consegue contornar isso desabilitando o botão no evento `submit` do formulário, mas neste caso talvez você possa verificar se é um botão do tipo `submit` e forçar manualmente a submissão.

Comment: Você acha q setar de disable para readonly possa resolver?

Comment: Um botão não pode ser `readonly`.

Comment: ops, dei uma gafe kkk

Comment: Você pode me ajudar um pouco mais em como eu faria o evento? Eu tinha feito na função do submit, mas como vou usar em varios botoes, eu queria fazer uma coisa generica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria algo assim:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[blockClicks]'
})
export class NoDblClickMatDirective {
    lastClick = 0;

    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {    
        const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        const ultimoClick = currentTime - this.lastClick;


        if (ultimoClick < 300) {//voce pode adaptar de acordo com o que vc considera um click duplo
            event.stopPropagation();
        } 
        this.lastClick = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta dando essa mensagem no `this.ultimoClick = currentTime` > A propriedade 'ultimoClick' não existe no tipo 'NoDblClickMatDirective'.

Comment: Voce pode me explicar o que pensou, eu nunca fiz diretiva entao nao entendo muito bem as ordens... o 300 sao a quantidade de clicks? o stopPropagation ele impede a função do botao? O q eu consideraria um click duplo por exemplo?

Comment: fiz quase isso que mandou, mas consegui, obrigado